Constraining a number to a looping range. Is there a more elegant function?
Take this function
func f(x,y) => x % y

Given the following inputs, here are the corresponding outputs.

f(0, 30) => 0
f(7.5, 30) => 7.5
f(15, 30) => 15
f(22.5, 30) => 22.5
f(30, 30) => 0

However, I want this output

f(0, 30) => 0
f(7.5, 30) => -7.5
f(15, 30) => 15
f(22.5, 30) => 7.5
f(30, 30) => 0

Or to put it another way, I want the output to be sort-of centred around y / 2 
I can achieve this with a few if statements so the function becomes...
f(x, y) => {
  var res = x % y;
  if (res === 0) return res;
  if (res === y / 2) return res;
  if (res > y / 2) return res - y / 2;
  if (res < y / 2) return res * -1;
}

But it feels like I'm brute forcing something that might have a more elegant solution. I'm terrible at mathematics and I don't have the vocabulary to even know what to look for.
So that's the question. Is there a more elegant solution for this function?

if (res > y / 2) return res - y / 2; if (res < y / 2) return res * -1; could probably be just res - y / 2 (not clear with examples provided why couldn't)

@Renat, yep, that's simpler. I was being explicit about the logic in the example. I guess I phrased the question poorly. What I'm wondering is if there's some mathematical formula or function I can use that does it without any if statements. The output feels similar to a sine wave. It just moves between 0 and 15 and flips the sign in sometimes. So it "feels" like I'm doing something that has already been expressed in a far simpler way than I'm doing it.

It seems that desired output of function is (chart was made with WolframAlpha):

If so, a one-liner could be
(x, y) => y/2 - ((x + y/2) % y)

but might want to consider more readable
(x, y) => {
    var modulo = x % y;
    if(modulo < y/2)
        return -modulo; 
    else
        return y - modulo;
}

